# Can't save pandas dataframe to HDF file

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I have been trying for a while to save a pandas dataframe to an HDF5 file. I tried various different phrasings eg. `df.to_hdf` etc. but to no avail. I am running this in a python virtual environment see [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). Even without the use of the VE it has the same error. The following script comes up with the error below:

```
''' This script reads in a pickles dictionary converts it to panda 
dataframe and then saves it to an hdf file. The arguments are the 
file names of the pickle files.
'''

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import sys

# read in filename arguments
for fn in sys.argv[1:]:
    print 'converting file %s to hdf format...' % fn
    fl = open(fn, 'r')
    data = pickle.load(fl)
    fl.close()
    frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
    fnn = fn.split('.')[0]+'.h5'
    store = pd.HDFStore(fnn)
    store.put([fn.split('.')[0]], frame)
    store.close()
    frame = 0
    data = 0
```

Error is:

```
$ ./p_to_hdf.py LUT_*.p
converting file LUT_0.p to hdf format...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./p_to_hdf.py", line 22, in <module>
    store = pd.HDFStore(fnn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 270, in __init__
    raise Exception('HDFStore requires PyTables')
Exception: HDFStore requires PyTables
```

`pip list` shows both pandas and tables are installed and the latest versions.

```
pandas (0.16.2)
tables (3.2.0)
```

Comment: Can you do `import tables` on its own? What happens when you try to import tables?

Comment: `import tables` happens without errors.

Comment: did you check if the packages are indeed inside the virtualenv and not outside ? try "which python" to check which python installation is in use in your enviroment

Comment: After `source ~/venv/bin/activate` I tried `which pytables` and `which tables` and I get `no pytables in ...`. I then tried `locate pytables` and it points to paths in the `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/` area only. Not sure what I should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution had noting to do with the code but how to `source` a virtual environment in python. The correct way is to use `. venv/bin/activate` instead of `source ~/venv/bin/activate`. Now `which python` shows the python installed under `~/venv/bin/python` and the code runs correctly.

Comment: So what should we do with the question title, which is misleading?